# When using a multi-dimensional array, What is the difference between using the pointer to that array and using actual array name as pointer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have this code, Which uses function to which a pointer to an array is passed

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(int ptr[][3])
{
     printf("%d %d",*ptr,*ptr+1);
}
void main()
{
    int arr[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int (*ptr)[3]=arr;
    func(ptr);
}
```

Now, If I pass the actual array name to the function as

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func(int ptr[][3])
{
     printf("%d %d",*ptr,*ptr+1);
}
void main()
{
    int arr[2][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int (*ptr)[3]=arr;
    func(arr);
}
```

Both of the above **code executes** and prints the same address. But what is the point of having a pointer if array name of multi-dimensional array does the same job.
Or is there any difference between them?

Comment: Pick a language please. One would not write such code in c++ at all.

Comment: You want 2nd example `func(ptr);` --> `func(arr);` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I want to know the difference between them

Comment: It seems that there is no difference between your first code and the second code.

Comment: Your two programs are exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
printf("%d %d",*ptr,*ptr+1);
```

...isn't doing what I'd guess you intend it to. In particular, the precedence means that `*ptr+1` means the same as `(*ptr)+1`, whereas I'd guess what you really wanted was:

```
*(ptr + 1)
```

To get an idea of the real difference between the two, it might make more sense to not dereference the pointers at all, and just print out the addresses:

```
void func1(int *a) { 
    printf("%p %p\n", (void *)a, (void *)(a+1));
}

void func2(int ptr[][3]) { 
    printf("%p %p\n", (void *)ptr, (void *)(ptr+1));
}

int main() { 
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3};
    printf("sizeof int == %d\n\n", (int)sizeof(int));
    func1(x);
    func2(&x);
}
```

Now let's look at the result:

```
sizeof int == 4

0x7ffe3f67ba20 0x7ffe3f67ba24
0x7ffe3f67ba20 0x7ffe3f67ba2c
```

The first shows addresses ending in f00 and f04. As shown, sizeof(int) == 4, so we're seeing pretty much what we expect--adding 1 to an `int *` yields a pointer to the next `int`, so the address is increased by 4.

In the second case, the addresses end with `a20` and `a2c`, so we're seeing a difference of `c` (12 decimal). In this case, it's not a pointer to an int--it's a pointer to an array of three ints. So, when we add one, the address changes by the size of an array of three ints of 4 bytes apiece (i.e., 3x4 = 12).

Comment: `int *x = {1, 2, 3};` --> `int *x = (int[]){1, 2, 3};`. Compile with `-Wall -Werror` ;-)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: We're simply looking at how the *type* of a pointer affects how math on that pointer works. The warning to which you refer is less relevant than the current phase of the moon.

Comment: You should read the compiler warning. " initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" , "excess elements in scalar initializer". Also Invalid pointer usage is UB. By the way I have not done downvote yet.

Comment: Why do you think `1` is a valid address as a pointer (to `int`)?

Comment: Why do you think a pointer that's never dereferenced has to meet any particular definition of "valid"? But, just for the sake of getting rid of this idiotic thread of nonsense, I've made an utterly irrelevant edit to the code.

Comment: _6.5.6 Additive operators p8 If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined._  It is undefined regardless of dereference.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: That's not the whole story. For these purposes, a non-array variable is treated as an array of one element, and computing "one past its end" is specifically allowed (offhand I don't know the section number in the C standard, but in the C++ standard it's at §[expr.unary.op]/3.

Comment: What you say is correct, but you need the first valid object in the first place.

Comment: What makes you think `x` was ever not a valid object?

Comment: E.g The `int` of address `1` is considered to be contrary to the alignment constraint.

Comment: Also There is no guarantee that there is an appropriate object at random addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> But what is the point of having a pointer if array name of multi-dimensional array does the same job.

The point is that an array is something completely different than a pointer and of course, you could have a pointer *without* an array.

The array holds many objects of the same type in a contiguous memory region. So pointer vs array makes a (**huge**) difference for the declaration.

Taking a pointer of an array just to pass it along is not necessary because that happens automatically in C. It doesn't hurt either.